# Selenium bot with percentages

Tags: python, selenium, bots

I'm stuck in problem where I want to program selenium/python bot which could answer my own survey. But I'm stuck in problem where I don't know/can't find solution. I want that selenium could choose from more than 1 xpath. But I don't know how to make that. Also is there a chance that you can make like random %? So e.g Vyras could have 70% chance and Moteris 30% to be picked
Pic.1 [MV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3OEc.png) Pic.2 [My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTLpc.png)

my survey: https://apklausa.lt/f/logistiniu-imoniu-veiklos-modernizavimo-galimybes-efwxu6w/answers/new.fullpage

Answer (score 0):

## issue in your code

make this change (fix your code here)

```py
protoas = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id=\'entry_3375494\']/div[2]/label[1]/div/div')
```

## Get data from page using javasscript

if you run this javascript code on the site you will get all the input values for each section/question and also the question itself, do with this as you may

```js
let sections = document.querySelector('section.entry.radio.required').toArray().map((section)=>{
    let section_id = document.querySelector(section).data('id');
    let question = document.querySelector(document.querySelector(section, 'div.question').contents().get(0)).text();
    let options =  document.querySelector('input[name='' + section_id + '']').toArray().map((input)=>{
        return {
            'question': question,
            'name': document.querySelector(input).attr('name'),
            'data-id': document.querySelector(input).data('id'),
            'text': document.querySelector(document.querySelector('input[data-id=' + document.querySelector(input).data('id') + ']').siblings()[0], 'div.value > div.text').text()
        }
    });
    return options;
});
```

using this javascript on after the page has loaded, you will then get the following data stored in the `sections` variable

each element of the `sections` variable is 1 question

in this element, there is the name and ids for each option as well as the text for each option

[image]

## Get data from Selenium

if you want to run this in python, jus call this code and then your data will be in the data variable

```py
data = driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('section.entry.radio.required').toArray().map((section)=>{let section_id = document.querySelector(section).data('id');let question = document.querySelector(document.querySelector(section, 'div.question').contents().get(0)).text();let options =  document.querySelector('input[name=\'' + section_id + '\']').toArray().map((input)=>{return {'question': question,'name': document.querySelector(input).attr('name'),'data-id': document.querySelector(input).data('id'),'text': document.querySelector(document.querySelector('input[data-id=' + document.querySelector(input).data('id') + ']').siblings()[0], 'div.value > div.text').text()}});return options;})")
```

## click options

#### Once you have the data, you can simply click the options you want by using the ID provided form the previous step

```py
data_id = 3375494 # Just set the data id here and then run this for each option you want to click
driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('input[data-id=" + data_id + "]').click()")
```

Comment: @Martynas with this you dont need to interact with the site, just get the data, look at it, then call the click optons and volia

Comment: wow Dean, I'm very grateful for your help, but it's a bit challenging for me to use JS because I never used it, could you please help me with the js?